# Parameters in static methods of java are thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, static

I have a web application in java JSP / Servlet

My query is :

If I have a util method as follows

```
public static String doUtil(String param) {

    //Some processing on param.........

    String result = someProcess(param);

    return result;

}
```

Query is if this method will be accessed in Servlet `Class.method(param)`, will it be thread safe for multiple request from different clients on internet ?

Comment: Java is not Javascript. Please make an effort to figure out the name of the language you're trying to learn.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enough information to decide if what you are doing is thread safe or not. For example, if `someProcess(param)` uses and changes some global state it may not be thread safe.

Comment: Don't ask about the thread safety of individual methods. What's important is the _data_ that they operate on. The central idea of thread safety is to prevent threads B, C, and D from seeing some collection of data in a temporary, inconsistent/invalid state while thread A is in the middle of updating it. The only data visible in your example is a single, `String` object. Strings in Java are immutable--it is impossible for any thread to update a string--so if all you are worried about is internal consistency within that one string, it's automatically thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you do not store the parameter values in the servlet's state, you don't have to worry about the thread-safety of your parameters. When parameters are passed from method to method as parameters and not stored in a shared state, they're safe.

Additionally, your parameter is of `String` type. The string type is immutable, and therefore thread-safe.

The above holds true for both static and  instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But only becasue you pass String which is immutable. Static metods are dangarous only if they modify some global state. Search Google for: 'function with no side effects'

Answer (score 0):

As per the example you have given , It seems as a pure static function.

**A function is called pure function if it always returns the same result for same argument values and it has no side effects like modifying an argument (or global variable) or outputting something. The only result of calling a pure function is the return value. Examples of pure functions are strlen(), pow(), sqrt() etc.**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-functions/

So here there is no global variables used so there will be no cases of thread safety.

Comment: You can't know that the `doUtil(...)` function in the example is pure without seeing the entire implementation (including the implementation of the `someProcess(...)` function that it calls.) If "process" is an apt name, then I would suspect that `someProcess()` changes the static, global state of the program.

Answer (score 0):

It will be thread-safe as long as the content of the function is thread-safe. E.g. if it's a pure function (works only on input data) it will be thread-safe. It if utilizes another static function which is not thread-safe, then it is also not thread-safe.